# Transfer function of full bridge inverter using mosfet and LLC circuit

Tags: inverter, transfer-function, full-bridge

I'm new at deriving transfer function and trying to derive the same for following circuit. It contains full bridge inverter circuit with input as 50 Vdc (50% duty cycle used to drive MOSFETs). Output of inverter circuit is given to LLC circuit. I've derived transfer function of individual LLC circuit but not able derive for full bridge inverter. Can any one describe how to derive transfer function of full bridge inverter circuit or combine transfer function of full bridge and LLC circuit?

Note : Input is 50 Vdc supply and output of combine circuit is voltage across 100E resistor.

[image: inverter schema]

Comment: Why 300 nH in parallel with 100 ohm?

Comment: 300nH is inductance of isolation transformer (1:1) and at the other side of transformer there is resistor load of 100Ohm.

Comment: What isolation transformer?

Comment: Transformer is used for isolating input signal before giving it to output load resistor 100E.

Comment: Where in your circuit?

Comment: 300nH inductor represents inductance of transformer. Isolation transformer not shown in the circuit but instead inductance of transformer has been shown .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no simple approach to determine the transfer function of a LLC circuit. I have seen papers applying extended describing functions ([EDF](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/handle/10919/40173)) to the structure but the resulting expression is intractable and difficult to use. The best approach in my opinion is simulating the circuit with a piece wise linear (PWL) simulator such as SIMPLIS or PSIM.

SPICE is a linear solver and must linearize point by point any nonlinear behavior. A PWL simulator, on the other hand, manipulates elements that are always linear. This is because a diode is not described by its Shockley equation but by a succession of linear segments: the current is flat for an anode-cathode voltage below \$V_f\$ and linearly increases with a \$\frac{1}{r_d}\$ slope afterwards. Two segments are therefore enough to describe the simplest diode. You can add more segments to obtain a better precision but it affects simulation time.

The below circuit works on the SIMPLIS demo version Elements. It describes a simple voltage-controlled oscillator-based modulator. The output voltage is fixed in this simple open-loop configuration:

[image]

Once the simulation is run (a few seconds), you can plot the control-to-output transfer function and apply your compensation strategy:

[image]